# How to set a double press key shortcut on Mavericks? i.e. double-press option-key for mission control

Tags: macos

I was wondering how can you set a double press key shortcut on Mavericks? i.e. double-press option-key for expose. I've search everywhere without a clear solution. I haven't even found an application that could do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [private.xml](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>custom</name>
    <identifier>custom</identifier>
    <autogen>__DoublePressModifier__ KeyCode::OPTION_L, KeyCode::OPTION_L,
    KeyCode::EXPOSE_ALL</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

You can also assign different functions to pressing and holding a key. This would make pressing the right command open Safari:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <vkopenurldef>
    <name>KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_SAFARI</name>
    <url>file:///Applications/Safari.app</url>
  </vkopenurldef>
  <item>
    <name>custom</name>
    <identifier>custom</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyOverlaidModifier__ KeyCode::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::COMMAND_R,
    KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_SAFARI</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```